# Drag to pan and scroll to zoom

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to make gnuplot behave more naturally, so that instead of currently:

```
drag -> nothing
scroll -> scroll (pan)
ctrl + scroll -> zoom
```

make it:

```
drag -> pan
scroll -> zoom
```

I'm guessing this should be tied to the front-end you are using. I'm using wxt on linux. x11 has the same behaviour.